# Where can I purchase replacement stickers for a current set?

Tags: stickers

My stickers for set 60035 are damaged and need to be replaced. Where can I obtain replacements?

Answer (score 5):

If the set is a recent release you can call LEGO's customer service and they will send you a replacement. If it is an older, discontinued set, you can find replacement stickers on BrickLink. Here are all the stickers listed: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=160